# I need to set up an HTML code to recieve a requests.post HTTP request from python

Tags: python, html, python-requests, weebly

This is my first question I've posted here so let me know if I need to add more information. I have set up a python code which utilizes requests.post to send an HTTP request to the website (the code shown below). I am trying to post the data that is sent from python to the weebly website I have created. I believe the easiest option for this would be to embed HTML code into the website, however I have never used HTML before and cannot find a good source to learn it.

Python code:

```
import requests
DataSent = {"somekey":"somevalue"}
url = "http://www.greeniethegenie123.weebly.com"
r = requests.post(url, data = DataSent)
print(r.text)
```

Edit: The question is how can I set up an HTML code to receive the request and post it on the website. Or if there is any other way to send the data that would work too. I just have a sensor recording numbers that I would like to post to the weebly website.

Edit: It looks like HTML is not possible to do this, does anyone have other advice for how to send data from a raspberry pi to a website? The main problem is the website needs to update the data every minute to be useful in what I am trying to do.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: HTML is not capable of handling GET/POST requests

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use Javascript instead of HTML to accomplish this.

HTML is used for the structure of a webpage, while javascript can be used for requests, updating content, and lots of other stuff.

Here are some links to help you out on HTML and Javascript:

[HTML Intro](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

[Javascript Intro](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp)

For requests with Javascript, I would recommend using Axios:
[Axios NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Here's a link explaining how to use Axios as well:
[Axios Tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/)

Comment: OP already has code to send the requests (it is right there in the original question). Now OP needs to receive those requests. Can you show an example of javascript in a weebly webpage which can accept a POST request?